# zipfile не распаковывает архив

Tags: python, python-2.x, zip, ziparchive

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import zipfile
root = "C:"
z = zipfile.ZipFile(root + '\\ProgramData\\boot//s0urc3.zip','r')
z.extractall()
```

Все выполняется без ошибок, но архив не распаковывается, почему?

Comment: Нет, он без пароля, 2 файла в нем

Comment: А вы в какой папке запускаете питон?

Comment: Я не в папке запускаю - F:\

Comment: Уточните, как именно вы запускаете?

Comment: Открываю консольку в F:\ и пишу python <имя скрипта.py>

Comment: И в F:\ не появляются распакованные файлы, так получается?

Comment: Он разве на F:\ распаковывать должен?

Comment: @AlexFirsov как написано в ответе — он распаковывает в текущую папку. Если текущая папка — F:\ то и распаковывает в F:\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Файлы распаковываются в текущую рабочую папку. Добавьте в начало скрипта:

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
```

Это покажет вам рабочую папку (обычно это папка, где лежит запускаемый скрипт) и там будут распакованные файлы

А в конец скрипта добавьте

```
z.close()
```

Чтобы указать папку, куда нужно сохранить, нужно передать ее в качестве параметра:

```
path_to_extract = 'C:\\Data'
z.extractall(path_to_extract)
```

Если в этой папке окажутся файлы с именами, совпадающими с файлами в архиве, они будут перезаписаны **без предупреждения**.

Comment: Я думал он распаковывает файлы архива там, где и архив лежит, а можно как то указать чтобы он распаковывал по моему пути?

Comment: Можно. Просто укажите путь в качестве параметка - ``z.extractall(path_to_extract)``